# Vim delete every line until character

Tags: vim

I have a file containing around 200 such lines. I want to delete all the characters except the power measurement in each line.

For example, in the below line I want only "12125.0". How can I do it in vim? I know I need to use a regex but unfortunately I'm not an expert in it.

```
muid=af529d1d-8fcc-4390-a921-120cbb90792f;timestamp=1486766726447;targets=17329;devices=cpu;power=12125.0 mW
```

Comment: `:1,$s/^.*;power=\([0-9.]*\) .*$/\1/` would do it, I believe

Comment: many ways to skin a cat `:%norm 0/power=/<c-v><esc>eld0`